# SQL Joined Tables - Multiple rows on joined table per 'on' matched field merged into one row?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, pivot, window-functions

I have two tables I am pulling data from.  Here is a minimal recreation of what I have:

```
Select
 Jobs.Job_Number,
 Jobs.Total_Amount,
 Job_Charges.Charge_Code,
 Job_Charges.Charge_Amount
From
 DB.Jobs
Inner Join
 DB.Job_Charges
On
 Jobs.Job_Number = Job_Charges.Job_Number;
```

So, what happens is that I end up getting a row for each different Charge_Code and Charge_Amount per Job_Number.  Everything else on the row is the same.  Is it possible to have it return something more like:

```
Job_Number - Total_Amount - Charge_Code[1] - Charge_Amount[1] - Charge_Code[2] - Charge_Amount[2]
```

ETC?

This way it creates one line per job number with each associated charge and amount on the same line.  I have been reading through W3 but haven't been able to tell definitively if this is possible or not.  Anything helps, thank you!

Comment: What is the criteria to determine Charge_Code[1], & Charge_Amount[1]? Or they can be in any order?

Comment: These are just the iterations in the table.  For example, my left table (Jobs) has one instance of the Job_Number whereas my right table (Job_Charges) has three instances of that Job_Number, each with a different Charge_Code and Charge_Amount, thus the dataset returns three rows for that Job_Number.  I would like to display all three iterations of the Charge_Code and Charge_Amount on one row in the dataset that I am pulling into.  Hopefully this answers your question, I apologize if I misunderstood, I am still rather new to SQL.  Also, yes they can be in any order as long as it's the same Job.

Comment: I should also mention that I cannot alter the database itself, just the information that I have pulled from it.

Comment: Are the no of rows is limited to 3 or they can go till any limit?

Comment: It COULD go to any limit, but likely would never be more than 10.

Comment: Another point, I would like to keep these as separate columns.  I have seen a few articles that teach how to concatenate multiple rows worth of data into one column, which I do not want to do.  Thank you!

Comment: If you have another question, please post another question. Please don't ask questions in comments or multiple questions per post or change a post after reasonable answers. SO is not for "exploration", it is for answers to single specific questions. I have rolled back your question to the time of the accept. If you think that's a problem please read [help] links like [ask] & google with site:meta.stackexchange.com' & if you still disagree then flag this comment for moderator attention & explain why even though help/stackexchange says my rollback is OK.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments--please edit your post to move those clarifyin comments in then delete the comments. (Please not comments asking other questions.) Also, your question is a faq.  Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pivot your resultset over a fixed number of columns, you can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    job_number, 
    total_amount,
    max(case when rn = 1 then charge_code end) charge_code1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then charge_amount end) charge_amount1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then charge_code end) charge_code2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then charge_amount end) charge_amount2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then charge_code end) charge_code3,
    max(case when rn = 3 then charge_amount end) charge_amount3 
from (
    select
        j.job_number,
        j.total_amount,
        c.charge_code,
        c.charge_amount,
        row_number() over(partition by job_number, total_amount order by c.charge_code) rn
    from DB.Jobs j
    inner join DB.Job_Charges c on j.job_number = c.job_number
) t
group by job_number, total_amount
```

The above query handes up to 3 charge codes and amounts par job number (ordered by job codes). You can expand the `select` clause with more `max(case ...)` expressions to handle more of them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am having difficulty getting this to work.  I am going to break it down and better analyze it so I can recreate it for my purpose.  Thank you!

Comment: @NMALM: which difficulty are you exactly having?

Comment: I actually got it to work now, but I am still having difficulty adding in all my additional stuff I need from this.  I will update once I've tried a bit myself.  Thank you!

Comment: I currently have this working how I need it to, however I am using 40 lines (20 each of charge_code and charge_amount) just for the charges.  There has to be a more elegant way of doing this.  I'm still playing around with it and I'll report any success.

Comment: I rolled back the asker's editing of another question at the bottom of their post after the accept. See my comments on the question.