# Making adjustments to Select fields dynamically - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop, while-loop

This is a previous question of mine: [SQL Joined Tables - Multiple rows on joined table per 'on' matched field merged into one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887202/sql-joined-tables-multiple-rows-on-joined-table-per-on-matched-field-merged)

What I'm curious about is how to adjust my statement dynamically.  I will have an SQL statement that will look for a reference number in a database table.  Each reference number might return any number of result lines each with a set of dimensions (length x width x height).  This is what I currently have:

```
select
reference_no,
max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_length end) length1,
max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_width end) width1,
max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_height end) height1,
max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_length end) length2,
max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_width end) width2,
max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_height end) height2,
max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_length end) length3,
max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_width end) width3,
max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_height end) height3
from
table.data
where
reference_no = {reference number}
group by
reference_no;
```

What I need is to repeat my max statements for each line based on how many lines there are for that reference number.  Is that even possible?  I am curious if there is a way to make a simulated for loop to iterate over each line (https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/for_loop.php)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't do much postgresql, but...

You're wanting to take pre-pivoted data and pivot it differently, and dynamically based on the values available within your filter?  You're probably not going to do that using a straight query.

Here's the basic concept:

1. Unpivot your pre-pivoted data into something that is more normalized (and generally useful).
2. Pivot those results into the output you want.

Here is some code for SQL Server that may point you in the right direction.  This is based on code I found at https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/ (...which has moved, but I found it again.  Bookmarking may not be helpful in the long-term.)  You should be able to convert this to be compatible with postgresql by...

...searching for `postgresql pivot` and `postgresql unpivot`.  You'll find results like these:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html (crosstab)
https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/unpivot-with-postgres/ (cross join using the values clause)

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable (
    [myTableID] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [reference_no] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [line_no] INTEGER NULL,
    [dimensions_length] INTEGER NULL,
    [dimensions_width] INTEGER NULL,
    [dimensions_height] INTEGER NULL
);
GO


INSERT INTO #myTable([reference_no],[line_no],[dimensions_length],[dimensions_width],[dimensions_height]) 
VALUES
  ('A1T 9Q5',1,10,2,5)
, ('A1T 9Q5',2,1,3,7)
, ('A1T 9Q5',3,6,3,4)
, ('A1T 9Q5',4,5,10,2)
, ('A2M 6U4',1,10,6,4)
, ('A2M 6U4',2,9,6,8)
, ('A2M 6U4',3,1,8,10)
, ('A2M 6U4',4,7,10,9)
, ('A7E 7Q5',1,3,5,5)
, ('A7E 7Q5',2,6,5,4)
, ('A7E 7Q5',3,2,4,10)
, ('A7E 7Q5',4,1,2,7)
, ('C2W 2D3',1,3,3,7)
, ('C2W 2D3',2,7,3,1)
, ('C2W 2D3',3,5,1,3)
, ('C2W 2D3',4,4,6,2)
, ('C7M 0L0',1,7,2,8)
, ('C7M 0L0',2,9,6,8)
, ('C7M 0L0',3,10,6,7)
, ('C7M 0L0',4,8,1,2)
, ('E2R 6G6',1,9,2,5)
, ('E2R 6G6',2,3,10,10)
, ('E2R 6G6',3,5,8,7)
, ('E2R 6G6',4,6,9,6)
, ('F2J 1X1',1,7,2,6)
, ('F2J 1X1',2,2,5,4)
, ('F2J 1X1',3,8,3,4)
, ('F2J 1X1',4,7,8,10)
, ('F7Q 8X4',1,7,1,5)
, ('F7Q 8X4',2,9,7,6)
, ('F7Q 8X4',3,7,9,4)
, ('F7Q 8X4',4,6,7,4)
, ('G1U 1K7',1,1,9,3)
, ('G1U 1K7',2,7,7,3)
, ('G1U 1K7',3,8,10,4)
, ('G1U 1K7',4,7,2,6)
, ('J6J 5H5',1,7,8,7)
, ('J6J 5H5',2,5,2,4)
, ('J6J 5H5',3,3,8,4)
, ('J6J 5H5',4,10,10,5)
, ('J5G 6W7',1,1,7,7)
, ('J5G 6W7',2,9,3,10)
, ('J5G 6W7',3,2,7,1)
, ('J5G 6W7',4,5,5,10)
, ('L3W 6T8',1,10,1,7)
, ('L3W 6T8',2,2,3,3)
, ('L3W 6T8',3,3,7,10)
, ('L3W 6T8',4,5,9,10)
, ('L9T 8I1',1,10,4,6)
, ('L9T 8I1',2,4,9,4)
, ('L9T 8I1',3,2,2,1)
, ('L9T 8I1',4,4,5,7)
, ('N6B 3N5',1,10,6,10)
, ('N6B 3N5',2,10,5,9)
, ('N6B 3N5',3,9,3,10)
, ('N6B 3N5',4,7,8,8)
, ('N6B 3N5',5,6,9,8)
, ('P1L 1M5',1,1,9,9)
, ('P1L 1M5',2,9,4,8)
, ('P1L 1M5',3,3,3,4)
, ('P1L 1M5',4,5,2,5)
, ('Q4D 7I0',1,8,7,5)
, ('Q4D 7I0',2,10,7,7)
, ('Q4D 7I0',3,2,5,3)
, ('Q4D 7I0',4,6,2,4)
, ('Q4D 7I0',5,2,10,5)
, ('R1P 6J1',1,2,8,3)
, ('R1P 6J1',2,2,10,6)
, ('R1P 6J1',3,2,9,4)
, ('R1P 6J1',4,2,6,8)
, ('V2B 7A4',1,1,9,8)
, ('V2B 7A4',2,10,2,4)
, ('V2B 7A4',3,8,10,10)
, ('V2B 7A4',4,5,7,5)
, ('V2B 7A4',5,4,1,9)
, ('S3H 1V5',1,8,2,1)
, ('S3H 1V5',2,2,4,5)
, ('S3H 1V5',3,3,8,5)
, ('S3H 1V5',4,2,5,6)
, ('W3J 5E0',1,4,2,9)
, ('W3J 5E0',2,2,6,10)
, ('W3J 5E0',3,10,3,9)
, ('W3J 5E0',4,5,5,1)
, ('X7M 6D2',1,10,6,3)
, ('X7M 6D2',2,1,6,7)
, ('X7M 6D2',3,2,7,8)
, ('X7M 6D2',4,8,3,6)
, ('Z2M 1Q5',1,4,3,7)
, ('Z2M 1Q5',2,6,7,7)
, ('Z2M 1Q5',3,9,2,4)
, ('Z2M 1Q5',4,2,6,4)
, ('Y7T 4V4',1,2,7,8)
, ('Y7T 4V4',2,9,5,9)
, ('Y7T 4V4',3,10,8,9)
, ('Z9N 3I6',1,3,7,9)
, ('Z9N 3I6',2,6,9,2)
, ('Z9N 3I6',3,1,7,8)
, ('U8E 9O6',1,10,10,7)
, ('U8E 9O6',2,7,1,4)
, ('U8E 9O6',3,4,7,1)
;

/*
select reference_no
, line_no
, max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_height end) height1
, max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_height end) height2
, max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_height end) height3
, max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_length end) length1
, max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_length end) length2
, max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_length end) length3
, max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_width end) width1
, max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_width end) width2
, max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_width end) width3

from #myTable

where reference_no in ('U8E 9O6', 'V2B 7A4', 'L3W 6T8', 'C2W 2D3')

group by reference_no
, line_no

order by 1, 2
;
*/



DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
declare @refno varchar(50)
                           set @refno = 'U8E 9O6'
                           --set @refno = 'V2B 7A4'

SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(col)
  FROM (SELECT distinct p.col FROM (
        select reference_no
        , dim + cast(line_no as varchar(50)) as col
        , val

        from (
            select reference_no
            , line_no
            , dimensions_length as length
            , dimensions_width as width
            , dimensions_height as height
            from #myTable
            where reference_no = @refno
        ) a
        unpivot (
        val for dim in (length, width, height)
        ) as unpvt
   ) AS p
  GROUP BY p.col) AS x;
print @columns

SET @sql = N'
SELECT p.reference_no, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM (
  SELECT p.reference_no, p.col, p.val
   FROM (
        select reference_no
        , dim + cast(line_no as varchar(50)) as col
        , val

        from (
            select reference_no
            , line_no
            , dimensions_length as length
            , dimensions_width as width
            , dimensions_height as height
            from #myTable
            where reference_no = ''' + @refno + '''
        ) a
        unpivot (
        val for dim in (length, width, height)
        ) as unpvt
   ) AS p
) AS j
PIVOT (
  max(val) FOR col IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;


drop table #myTable
```

And next time... providing your own sample database structure and sample data will speed things along.

Answer (score -1):

You could easily use the answer from the other question (poor form, sir) and add lines to the code you already have (and accept the NULLs).

```
select
reference_no,
max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_length end) length1,
max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_width end) width1,
max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_height end) height1,
max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_length end) length2,
max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_width end) width2,
max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_height end) height2,
max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_length end) length3,
max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_width end) width3,
max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_height end) height3,
max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_length end) length4,
max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_width end) width4,
max(case when line_no = 1 then dimensions_height end) height4,
max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_length end) length5,
max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_width end) width5,
max(case when line_no = 2 then dimensions_height end) height5,
max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_length end) length6,
max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_width end) width6,
max(case when line_no = 3 then dimensions_height end) height6
-- etc. to the maximum expected number of line_no values
from
table.data
where
reference_no = {reference number}
group by
reference_no;
```

Comment: This is what I am currently doing.  The point of the question is to see if there is a way to minimize the query and handle things more programmatically.  The other issue is that I have no idea how many to set as there is no cap on the number there could be.  So I wanted a catchall to see how many there were and repeat the statement that many times.  I am looking over your previous answer to see if there is info there that I could use.